# Accessing a pointer to integer within a pointer to structure

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

I am having a difficult time trying to access `*testscores` from `*stPtr`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct GradeInfo{
    char name;
    int *testscores;
    double average;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GradeInfo var;
    *var.testscores = 10;
    cout << *var.testscores;

    GradeInfo *stPtr = &var;

    // This line of code breaks my test program
    cout << stPtr->testscores;

    return 0;
}
```

I would sincerely appreciate it if you could help me access the pointer to integer variable within the pointer to structure variable I have declared.

Comment: You should initialize var.testscores because it's a pointer

Comment: `*var.testscores = 10;` What exactly is `testscores` pointing at for you to access that address?

Comment: you haven't allocated any space for the pointer `testscores` to point at.

Comment: _"I am having a difficult time"_ and _"This line of code breaks my test program"_ are not problem descriptions. What happened? If you got any errors, quote them in full.

Answer (score 1):

You should first allocate space for it to store actual data:

```
*var.testscores = new int[5];
```

The you can access it:

```
var.testscores[3] = 100;
```

Note the `->` operator does not dereference the member. You should add an extra asterisk or use brackets:

```
cout << *stPtr->testscores;
cout << stPtr->testscores[3];
```

Should be OK by then.

Comment: And of course, don't forget to `delete[]` that array later. And then realise you should just be using `std::vector` instead. :P

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer is not initialized. Either initialize it with `new` or, better, use smart pointers such as `unique_ptr` which will handle deletion of your data automatically.

Comment: They want a dynamic array, so they should use an `std::vector`, not a smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You this code below. You haven't allocated memory for integer pointer.

Note: Don't forget to release the allocated memory with new.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct GradeInfo{
    char name;
    int *testscores;
    double average;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GradeInfo var;
    var.testscores = new int(10);
    cout << *var.testscores << endl;

    GradeInfo *stPtr = &var;

    cout << *(stPtr->testscores) << endl;

    delete(var.testscores);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to release the memory with `delete`. Don't just say it, write it in your code.

Comment: I added a note dude. Go through the post again. Note: Don't forget to release the allocated memory with new.